# I want to create a input filter and buffer allowing only a particular type of data packets on a port

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, packets

I want to create a input filter and buffer allowing only a particular type of data packets on a port and then parse it. Which is the best method i can use. I have a system architecture in place but confused about the packet reception. Here is the architecture brief.

- **Input filter and buffer** allows selecting only particular data packets to unload the system at "peak" loads and protect against the deliberate or accidental attacks.
- **Sorter** distributes packets to destinations (parse-relay) and sends back an ACK packets to object module.
- **Parser** identifies the data from incoming packets, converts them to specified algorithms, or modes of data storage, and sends to the database.
  Relay Manager creates the necessary number of relay circuits and manage their settings
- **MySQL database** stores incoming object data, event logs and all settings, and is used to send commands to the object module.
  To protect database from the user applications direct requests (eg for remote access), user applications can use HTTP interface, via a web server and PHP scripts.

Comment: _"but confused about the packet reception"_ Could you clarify what you're confused about?

Comment: how the packets will be recieved and sorted.